# python map/lambda and ascii error

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, ascii, tweets

This is my first time doing a text mining project and using Panda.  I am trying to collect all the strings in the "text" label in the downloaded live tweets (json format), so I can tokenize all the tweets and count the high frequency words.  Here is a sample tweet in the json format:

```
{
    "contributors": null, 
    "truncated": false, 
    "text": "Hey Don : TheCougCoach :) Want to get iPh0ne 6 for FREE? Kindly check my bi0. Thx https://t.co/c38b8vqq2O", 
    "is_quote_status": true, 
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null, 
    "id": 659549062023262209, 
    "favorite_count": 0, 
     ...... skip
     },
    "quoted_status_id": 659548944251228160, 
        "retweeted": false, 
        "coordinates": null, 
        "timestamp_ms": "1446083724872", 
        "quoted_status": {
            "contributors": null, 
            "truncated": false, 
            "text": "I understand He is a criminal but Donald has all the right to be in the discussion. https://t.co/qv3oScGA1U", 
            "is_quote_status": true, 
            "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
```

Here is my code (Python 2.7 + panda 0.17.0):

```
import json  
import pandas as pd
tweets_data_path = 'tweet.txt'
tweets_data = []
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")
for line in tweets_file:
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        tweets_data.append(tweet)
    except:
        continue

tweets = pd.DataFrame()

tweets['text'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['text'], tweets_data)

print tweets['text']

print tweets['text'].astype(str) # Try to convert the panda series into strings so I can tokenize the tweets (strings after "text" in the json format) using regular expression
```

Here is the output

```
0     Hey Don : TheCougCoach :) Want to get iPh0ne 6...
1     I understand He is a criminal but Donald has a...
Name: text, dtype: object

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 125-126: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Two questions:

(1)
    tweets = pd.DataFrame()

```
tweets['text'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['text'], tweets_data)
```

Here panda together with map/lambda provides an easy way to get the data after "text" in the tweet json file.  However, "map" only allows the matched length of lists, making the output uncompleted (with ... ending).  Is there any better way to code it?

(2)

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 125-126: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It seems like the input "tweet.txt" is in unicodes, so we encounter the error? If yes, should we encode the "tweet.txt" when reading it?  The actual input file is quite large (several GBs or even bigger), so is there more efficient way to address this issue?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't load the JSON file line by line. The JSON module supports loading a file in one go: `

```
with open(tweets_data_path) as fp:
    tweets_data = json.load(fp)
```

Now step through `tweets_data` as you normally would steps through lists and dicts.

The point is that a JSON does not necessarily need newlines after every key-value entry; the fact that the text file happens to have that format is nice, but you should not rely on it.

As for the unicode issue, I would suggest to use Python 3 instead and circumvent a bunch of these issues.
The [JSON module documentation for Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) says the following, though:

> If the contents of fp are encoded with an ASCII based encoding other than UTF-8 (e.g. latin-1), then an appropriate encoding name must be specified. Encodings that are not ASCII based (such as UCS-2) are not allowed, and should be wrapped with codecs.getreader(encoding)(fp), or simply decoded to a unicode object and passed to loads().